# Twitter profile widget sometimes does not render

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

```
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 20,
  interval: 4000,
  width: 'auto',
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#e1e1e1',
      color: '#0e89c7'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#444444',
      links: '#6c8711'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: true,
    loop: false,
    live: true,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: false,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}).render().setUser('xxxxxxxxxxx').start();
</script>
```

I don't know why but sometimes it does not render.

someone could tell me why?

thanks.

Comment: Could it be that widgets.twimg.com sometimes is slow or down? Are you calling other external scripts on the same page that might slow it down even more?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible that Twitter itself could be down, Twitter's API could be down, your API limit (number of requests) has been reached, or that twimg.com is down (as of this posting, twimg.com is down for me).

The first thing your script does is load js from twimg.com. You can try to save that file locally, and just run it from your server instead of twimg... there's a chance it might still work, and it wouldn't require your site to hit twimg.com each time (then again, I don't know this particular widget).

While the widget approach is pretty easy, Twitter has a pretty easy API that you can interact with yourself, if you feel like reducing the number of servers in the equation. For example, this will get you a bunch of json data for a user:

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=**some username**

To "properly" do this, you'll want some kind of caching system in place so that you don't constantly ping twitter each time someone visits your site.  For this, you'll have to get dirty with a little server-side code, such as PHP.  It's not that bad to learn though, and there are lots of [tutorials on how to do it](http://spaceninja.com/2009/07/twitter-php-caching/).

Good luck!